# Set builder modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a set **C** which is defined as: $$ C= \{ (x|x\in \mathbb  Z^+) \land ( x \pmod 3 < 2)    \} $$

To find such an **x**, we have: $x = 3n + 1$

But what am I limited to in this case? if $ n=1  $ then $x=4$. But am I limited to positive integers less than two? Meaning:  $C=\{4\}$

I'm a little confused here.

Answer (score 0):

$C=\{1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,15,16,18,19,21,22,24,25,\dots\}$,

all positive integer $x$ belongs there which is of the form $3n$ or $3n+1$, i.e. $x \ {\tt mod}\, 3=0$ or $1$.